# Techniques to deal with "not all code paths return a value" when your algorithm already takes care of it

Tags: c#, algorithm, compiler-errors

In C#, sometimes there are code paths that don't return a value, and it is nice that the compiler errors out, and allows you to fix them. However there are times where there STRUCTURALLY is a place where it doesn't, but the ALOGIRTHM would prevent that structure from happening.

Here is a simple contrived example.

```
public static int test1(bool a)
    {
        if (a) return 1;
        if (!a) return 2;
    }
```

Of course people will tell me , that my "algorithm" is stupid and my second test is redundant and I should just do.

```
public static int test1(bool a)
    {
        if (a) return 1;
        else return 2;
    }
```

or even

```
public static int test1(bool a)
    {
        if (a) return 1;
        return 2;
    }
```

I purposely choose this simple "Redundant" example, rather than my real world algorithms, as I want to focus on this issue specifically, not about 10 different ways I could have written the algorithm :)

So what are the possible ways to deal with this, and what are the pro's and con's of each.

1) is what we just covered, and that's refactor the algorithm. Sometimes this may not be possible, or the end result may not be as per formant, easy to read/understand or maintain.

other is just to return something that would never happen, such as null.. but in this case i'm dealing with an integer and i'd have to put 0, which feels ever dirtier

```
public static int test1(bool a)
    {
        if (a) return 1;
        if (!a) return 2;
        //this code never happens, but i need to keep the compiler happy
        return 0;
    }
```

or use exceptions

```
public static int test1(bool a)
    {
        if (a) return 1;
        if (!a) return 2;
        throw new Exception("this code never happens, but i need to keep the compiler happy");
    }
```

however every time I've dealt with this , no matter what technique I take i'm not happy with the result and feel a little dirty.

Are there alternatives?

Comment: this thread, discusses the issue some and at least has a good example of how a little refactoring can cause this to pop up. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22bea5fe-d3c3-4aaa-ae1a-d8033e6476a3/programatically-turn-off-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value

Comment: Throw. That's what exceptions are for. It is similar to a `switch` statement where you know all cases are handled. In the `default:` section you can throw.

Comment: Show me a real-world example of where this can't be handled by a trivial refactoring and I'll remove my close vote.

Comment: catch (Exception ex) { customexceptionprocessor(ex) } , where if it wasn't a separate function it would know that it would either return or throw, but it can't

Comment: and https://gist.github.com/klumsy/6251788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a compile error that all your code paths do not return a value, there is no flag to set or "trick," you have to either return a default value or throw an exception.  I'm a firm believer in throwing an InvalidOperationException("Unexpected code reached, this method has been modified incorrectly").

Why it's not dirty: if someone else comes along and makes a change that causes your exception to be thrown, they'll know they did something that the author of the exception viewed as fundamentally wrong.  Returning a default value could quietly break the consumers of the method, so it's good practice to use an exception as a safety net.

Comment: Yeah if there aren't any other technical ways to do it (other than refactor algorithm, return a dummy value, or default, or null, zero, or throw an exception, then what you suggest is probably the best, as it shows the intent, and if for some reason it does get executed, the maintainer has a good starting place to understand your code.

Comment: also it is true, that if that code path actually happened, it would be an extremely EXCEPTIONAL event.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you throw `Exception`s when there is an exceptional case... a bool not being `true` or `false` would be rather exceptional! I would throw an exception to keep the compiler happy, but also because you don't know how the method could change in the future.

I wouldn't consider an `if ... else` as dirty when dealing with a bool for exactly the reason that you use bools, they only have two values, when there are more possibilities (i.e. a string) then you can use more complex test.

Comment: +1 for this. Another exceptional case would be your implementation of the algorithm being buggy and not actually handling all the cases even though you think it does. In this case, it's nice to get an exception thrown to point out there's a real problem.

Comment: + 1 . Throwing an exception here makes sense, since this will mean that the algorithm faced an unexpected situation.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant when I said about the method changing in the future. I think the issue is that you're dealing with each test case in a separate `if` which means that every one of these explicit tests could fail, leaving the compiler with nowhere to go.

Comment: yeah, again i'm not interested in the alogorithm. I Just choose that as one of the smallest possible examples to generate a case where by nature of the algorithm code couldn't go a certain way, yet structurally it could.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int test1(bool a)
    {
        return a ? 1 : 2;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to change the algorithm.. in this case its a very simple thing that as above with a different operator could be refactored into an expression, but often it be have a bunch of comparisons, multiple branches with blocks of statements, multiple different returns and conditions, while loops etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable and assign the value to it and then return that value at the end of the function.

```
private bool isValid() 
{
bool result = false;
try {
    //some code 
    result = true;
    } catch {
    result = false;
    }
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might consider in this case is using the [Debug.Fail()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z60kt1f.aspx) method.

```
public static int test1()
{
    if (myComplexAlgo()) return 1;
    if (myCatchAllAlgo()) return 2;
    Debug.Fail("I should never be here!");
    return -1;
}
```

It isn't a good fit for everyone, the advantage in this method is that you can use it to make sure your tests fail without possibly crashing your production code. This can (hopefully) catch future problems in the code in case your algorithm or conditions change.